# cant login to change router settings

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip

I've been digging the net for IP addresses to log into my router but I've had no luck. The problem is there is a neighbor stealing my signal and I want to change the password. My IPv4 is: 192.168.1.6 When i enter it on the browser it won't let me log in the router settings. My router is a znid-gpon-2426a-2ts

Here are the specs for my network:

SSID:   Yasmin

Protocolo:  802.11n

Tipo de seguridad:  WPA2-Personal

Dirección IPv4: 192.168.1.6

Servidores DNS IPv4:    190.96.9.250
    190.153.164.250

Fabricante: Qualcomm Atheros Communications Inc.

Descripción:    Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter

Versión del controlador:    10.0.0.338

Dirección física:   ‎A4-17-31-C8-0A-6B

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: "won't let me log in" does not tell us much, please add details.

Comment: Have you tried 190.96.9.250 or 190.153.164.250?

Comment: Why not factory reset the box and start over with the configuration? I also is probaly easier if you connect your computer by cable to do the inital setup.

Comment: if **your** IP address is 192.168.1.6, then your router is most likely at 192.168.1.1. It's certainly not going to be the same as your own IP. Many routers are set to not allow admin over wifi… which is wise, as it means a bad actor has to actually be physically wired to your ethernet to get access. Once you get control back from your bad actor, setting that would be very wise.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://whatsmyrouterip.com and copy and paste the "local/private" IP into your browser's address bar. If it doesn't work, click "no, continue probing" and try again with the new **private** IP.

Essentially there are several different types of IP address and I think you are trying to use the wrong one. What you want is your **router**'s **private** IP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is.

In case you believe someone has access to your network who should not and you **are not able to login** into your router, simply reset(hard reset) the device to factory settings.

Only after doing this you can be sure that only you and people you give access are able to connect.

Most devices have a switch/button which you need to to hold for a number of seconds, to reset the router to factory settings.

You should have your ISP credentials at hand, because you will have to to reconfigure your router.

For your device follow this [steps](https://www.hardreset99.com/routers/zhone/zhone-znid-gpon-2426a-eu-reset/)

```
Power on the Zhone Router, place a paper clip or Pin into the hole on the back of the Router labeled Reset.
Hold paper clip or pin down for 10 to 15 seconds and release.
The Router will reboot on its own. Once the WLAN light stops blinking, the Router is reset.
Please Note, Resetting the Zhone router does not reset the firmware to an earlier version. It will only change all settings back to factory defaults.
```

Once your Zhone router has been reset, it goes back to it’s factory defaults settings.

```
IP address: 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1
Username: admin
Password: admin
OR see back side of your device.
```

Wifi won't work till you configure it. So you have to connect with cable until you reconfigured it.

Make sure to use a strong password for Wifi and don't give physical access to your router to people you don't trust.